# MySQL Prepared PDO statement is removing backslashes

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo

Using Symfony 3, XAMPP and php 5.6

I have a form where a user can upload a .csv file, and the rows should be inserted into a table

```
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $file = $form->get('memberList')->getData();

            $db = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
            $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE `MemberList` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

I then get the following error

> An exception occurred while executing 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\xampp\tmp\php198.tmp' INTO TABLE `MemberList` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '
>   ' IGNORE 1 LINES;':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 29 File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\xampp mpphp198.tmp' not found (Errcode: 22 "Invalid argument")

I stepped through the code in a debugger, and the file is successfully being uploaded to `C:\xampp\tmp\php198.tmp`. I've just no idea why it's looking for a file at `C:\xampp\mysql\data\xampp mpphp198.tmp`, which seems to be causing the issue as nothing exists there

Update: tried it with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and now get

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7890 Can't find file 'C:xampp mpphp2F24.tmp'.

The temporary file being created is actually C:\xampp\tmp\php2F24.tmp

**Update 2: I'm an idiot**, it's clearly escaping the backslashes - but why? I thought preparing with PDO would leave these intact

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Always use forward slashes ('/') in file paths. Yes, windows is quite happy about it and it saves so much hassle with all the standard linux stuff that is run on windows. The only issue is that you need to enclose the filepaths in double quotes when using the command line.

Comment: Nice to know windows won't complain (I thought it would), but since I'm not writing the file location myself I think I'll stick with my solution below

Answer (score -1):

Managed to get it working with this

```
        $db = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE member_list CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;";
        $pdo = $db->prepare($sql);
        $pdo->execute(array($file));
        $pdo->closeCursor();
```